# PayPal Change 'Cancel and return to' text

Tags: paypal

I have a PayPal account and have multiple buy now buttons on my site to allow users to purchase multiple tiers of my services. The issue is on the checkout page, the link at the bottom says "Cancel and return to me@foo.com" which is my email and I want to change it to my website's name.

I don't have a bussiness account and I managed to change it on the sandbox account, but I can't remember how I did it. The "cbt" tag isn't working for me either.

This is how it looks:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I know that if you're using the Express Checkout API you can set that value using the BRANDNAME parameter.

With Payments Standard, though, I'm not sure you can do it.  You could check your PayPal profile under Custom Payment Pages.  It may let you adjust that there, but then it would be the same for every site.

Express Checkout is the only way you could customize it per website/checkout.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm finding this to be the case as well

Answer (score 1):

**YOU CAN DO IT IF YOU HAVE A BUSINESS ACCOUNT ON PAYPAL SITE.**

Business accounts will display the business name on the account providing you have the Business Name field populated in your Account Profile.

Login to your Account.
Click on the Profile link.
Under Account Information.
Click on Business Information.

*What do you have for the Business Name?*

If you don't have a Business Name there, next to the Business Contact Name, click on ***Change Name***.
Select the Radio Button for Business Name Change.
Click on Continue.
Make the changes and save.

Logout of your Account. (All done :)

Next delete your web browser's cookies, temp files, history, etc.,  then close your web browser, reopen it and retry one of your item buttons.   Go throught the PayPal Screens to see if anything has changed.